# Dual monitor for GeForce 940MX

Tags: external-monitor

I plugged in a 2nd monitor to my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. The monitor flashes with the HP logo and then stays black. I ran the command below:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000134Dsv000017AAsd000038E2bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

What should I do to make the 2nd monitor work? Thanks.